# We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code UNAUTHENTICATED

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to run a script that worked about a month ago.  Now get this error message.

We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code UNAUTHENTICATED.

Comment: If your using V8 try switching back to legacy ES5

Comment: Thanks.  I am sure now that approach would have worked, but updating the V8 was the solution chosen

Answer (score 0):

Google updated all back-end code pages to a new version, V8, so I just updated all the site pages according to the link:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150940648

Comment: Do you still have the problem or has it been resolved

Comment: It has been resolved.Google updated all back-end code pages to a new version, V8, so I just updated all the site pages according to the link:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150940648

Comment: I don't see any information regarding the suggested changes on that link.  But I have to admit I don't go to issue tracker that much.

Comment: Perhaps you would be willing to share your improvenments as answer.